# Creating Android magazine application with APPMK

Tags: java, android

I'm try to make an Android magazine application. Until now, the best and the simplest way is using **APPMK** http://www.appmk.com/. and my questions are :

1. Is it possible customize between using APPMK and coding in eclipse editor?
2. Can I retrieve the magazine's content from HTML, XML or JSon? Because in **APPMK**, the content get from pdf files.

Answer (score 0):

1. No you can't customize that application using Eclipse editor.
2. no you can't retrieve content from HTML, XML or JSON because the appmk convert PDF to image internally.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't customize that application using Eclipse editor.

no you can't retrieve content from HTML, XML or JSON because the appmk convert PDF to image internally.